# Simple code for Pascal Triangle without arrays or functions?

Tags: python, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to make a program that would output up to the `h`th row of a pascal triangle. I based my code from a binomial expansion calculator. My code works when `h` is less than 2, but for 3 and above the result is wrong and I don't understand why.

```
h = int(input("Enter the height of Pascal's triangle to be displayed: "))

result = ""

n = 1
k1 = 1
k2 = 1
ctr = 0
combi = 1

for i in range(h,1,-1):
    n *= i

for row in range(h):
    for column in range(row+1):
        ctr = h - column
        for j in range(ctr,1,-1):
            k1 *= j
        for k in range(column,1,-1):
            k2 *= k
        combi = int(n/(k1*k2))
    result += str(combi) + " "
    print(result)

    k1 = 1
    k2 = 1
    ctr = 1
    combi = 1
```

Comment: Please do not add images of code, instead, add the code as part of the question text using the editor

Comment: Sorry! Will do next time

Comment: You can edit your post and fix this one :)

Answer (score 1):

For pascal's triangle in simple approach to get element of row that is > 1 you simply add element that is directly above it and one that is above and to the left (if theres nothing right above or above and to the left you add only one number)
This way you get correct pascal's triangle row by row

Below function generates list of lists in this simple manner. I was not able to get your approach though

```
def pasc(n):
    res = [[1]]
    while len(res) < n:
        tmp = []
        for i in range(len(res[-1])+1):
            if i == 0 or i == len(res[-1]):
                tmp.append(1)
            else:
                tmp.append(res[-1][i-1] + res[-1][i])
        res.append(tmp)
    return res

for i in [' '.join(map(str,i)) for i in pasc(5)]:print(i)
```

Comment: How do you get at the "one that is above and to the left" if you do it "without the use of arrays" as the OP specified?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the effort to debug your code was more than the effort of starting over from scratch.  Here's one example of a simpler solution:

```
h = int(input("Enter the height of Pascal's triangle to be displayed: "))

for row in range(h):
    for column in range(row + 1):

        if column > row - column:  # reflection about center
            column = row - column

        result = 1

        for i in range(column):
            result = (result * (row - i)) // (i + 1)

        print(result, end=" ")

    print()
```

No arrays nor functions anywhere in sight.

Here's another [solution from The Oxford Math Center](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/76) website which I translated from Java to Python for you:

```
# http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/76
# edu.emory.oxford.paul.oser

# prompt user to enter the number of rows
numRows = int(input("How many rows of Pascal's triangle would you like? "))

# generate numRows rows...
for row in range(numRows):

    # the first value is always a 1
    value = 1

    # later values can be found by successively
    # multiplying by a fraction that initially is row/1
    numerator = row
    denominator = 1

    # we will have to perform a total of row multiplications,
    # and with each one, the numerator goes down by one
    # and the denominator increases by one.
    for pos in range(row + 1):
        print(value, end=' ')
        value = value * numerator // denominator
        numerator -= 1
        denominator += 1

    # start a new row
    print()
```

Again, no arrays nor functions anywhere in sight.